# add exception type to bit framework known exceptions

Tags: bit-framework

based on docs, there are some known exception types in bit-framework.

https://docs.bit-framework.com/docs/bit-server-side/web-api.html#exceptions

How can we extend this list?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at following code:

```
public class MyException : Exception, IKnownException /*Required*/, IHttpStatusCodeAwareException /*Optional >> Default is InternalServerError (500)*/
{
    public MyException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; } = HttpStatusCode.Conflict;
}
```

Hope this helps